# Chat program network freezing?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, freeze

Okay so I have been programming this chat for fun and came accross something on my way.
I'm not good with sockets at all, can someone please help with connecting these?

Client.java:

```
try {
    Socket server = new Socket("jakebobjo.com", 1234);
    InputStream in = server.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = server.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);

    pout.println(username + ": " + input.getText() + "\n");

    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String responce = bin.readLine();

    server.close();         
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error connection to host.");
}
```

Server.java:

```
try {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket client = listener.accept();

    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);

    pout.println(username + ": " + input.getText() + "\n");

    client.close();         
    listener.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error connecting to client.");
}
```

The program just freezes when those trigger idk why:/

Comment: you have to run the ServerSocket and Client side socket in separate threads. Sockets in Java are blocking sockets, and will block the program at runtime when it tries to read/write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Program is freezing because in both files You have asked the application to send message to other side without accepting the message at either side.The sequence should be like any of these two:

> Client send message - Server recieves message

or

> Server sends message - Client Recieves Message

.In your case none of sequence is followed that leading to DeadLock and your application is freezed. Change the sequence of statement in  Client file as:

```
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String responce = bin.readLine();
pout.println(username + ": " + input.getText() + "\n");
```

> > Note: 
> > 2)Start Server side program first and then start
> >     Client side program.  
> >  1)MoreOver on server side you have Closed the Socket without recieveing message from client. So after the client recieves message from
> >     server , when it tries to send message to server ,program will halt throwing
> >     Exception.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks cause that makes sense I just gotta figure stuff out.. lol